# now.js removing data from now space and saving it only in client

Tags: javascript, node.js, nowjs-sockets

i have just started using now.js.

i want to place some data using specific clientId in the shared now space between server and client. i then want to move that data out of the now space and keep it only in the specific client. which means i then want to remove the data from the now space so as not to clog my servers memory. my data will probably be a custom object or a specific function and not text. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This should now be a problem:
Set the var on the server, sync it to the client, and then delete it from the client and sync back.

Pseudo code:

Server side:
`now.foo = 'bar';`

Client side:
`var foo = now.foo;`
`delete now.foo;`

When the client syncs back to the server now.foo should no longer be defined.